# How to limit access to one project in a solution in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a development project, and the solution for the project is being developed in Visual Studio.  The Visual Studio `Solution` is made up of four `Project`s, one of which is named `Entities` and describes the persistence object model used throughout.  As the architect responsible for the structural integrity of the system, I'm finding myself frustrated by developers who are, seemingly at random, modifying the classes within `Entities`, often times commenting out critical `Properties` or `Methods` because the individual developer was "confused" by what was there (even though it's well documented).

So, is there a way to make a specific `Project` read-only within a `Solution`, or do I need to take `Entities` outside of the `Solution` and create a separately-compiled `Library` for the rest of the `Project` to reference?

Comment: Don't try to solve a people-problem through code. Throw pens at your coworkers until they stop messing with the code.

Comment: Aside from the object throwing solution (pens and other detritus), which I dont necessarily agree with, why not limit access to it via source control? We us a combination of tools with Mercurial to limit pushes and promotions to a small group of senior devs, but allow local commits all day long.

Comment: That may be a viable solution.  We're limited to using Rational Team Concert as a source control solution, and it's an outdated version at that.  However, every time I think RTC probably won't be able to resolve some complex issue, it comes through.  I'm grudgingly learning to like it (love is a long way off, however).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Referee the functionality on your Entities project for the project that use it by the dll, not the project. (And remove the project from your solution.)